# Register a method as a listener with aspectj

Tags: aop, aspectj

I already know how to intercept a method execution, but in this case, I will not call the method directly, it should be called when an event is fired (Observer pattern). How can i register that method as a listener using aspectj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspectJ as well as the AJDT for Eclipse contain code examples, including one implementing the Observer design pattern. Go to the [AspectJ documentation](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/index.html) page, select [Examples](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/examples/) and from there download the [source code](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/examples/examples.zip) archive.